# Bloomberg/Reuters share price to Google Sheets?

Tags: investing

I'm using Google Sheets to track my stocks. However, I do have quite a lot of international stocks that are not covered by Google Finance but is available on Reuters or Bloomberg.

If I would like this share price to be linked to a cell, what's the formula?

https://www.reuters.com/companies/CRAYON.OL

Bless,

Comment: What is the issue, Google Sheets doesn't recognize the ticker symbol?

Answer (score 1):

You should try prefixing your stocks with the correct exchange.  For example try NASDAQ:FB (Facebook listed on Nasdaq) instead of just FB, or try NYSE:IBM (IBM listed on NYSE Exchange) instead of just IBM.

Please note that as of late 2019 when the referenced article below was published,

> "Google Finance’s sheets integration ... doesn’t include most
>   international exchanges yet. So if you want to transact on Asian or
>   European exchanges, this may not be the best option for you."

Since the one you mention above, Crayon, appears to trade on the Oslo Stock Exchange, you will be out of luck for the time being unless Google recognizes the OTC equivalent which appears to be CRAYF trading on the OTCPK.  So you could try OTCPK:CRAYF or OTC:CRAYF.

Article: 
https://www.howtogeek.com/449743/how-to-track-stocks-with-google-sheets/